# How to get the count from a stream with an if condition inside the map?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
List<Employee> Employees = getEmployeeList();
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

Employees.stream()
        .map(item -> {
            UserProfile user = userDao.findById(item.getUserProfileId());
            if(("domainName").equals(user.getDomain()) && ("agencyCode").equals(user.getAgencyNumber())){
                count.getAndIncrement();
            }
            return item;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I need the count of the employee which satisfies the `if` condition. How can I remove the `count` variable and instead use the `count()` method of the Stream API?

Clarification : I wanted to filter out the employees which satisfy the current conditions mentioned in If block while i just have to call it once. what i was doing earlier, i will show.

```
List<Employee> Employees = getEmployeeList();
                Employee employee = Employees.stream()
                .filter(item -> ("domainName").equals(userDao.findById(item.getUserProfileId()).getDomain()))
                .filter(item -> ("agencyCode").equals(userDao.findById(item.getUserProfileId()).getAgencyNumber()))
                .findAny().orElse(null);
```

So i got the requirement to call the userDao method only once.

Comment: `Employees.stream().filter(item -> /* your condition */).count()`.

Comment: Side note: in your case instead of `map()` you could use `peek()`.

Comment: @Thomas in this case, that's unnecessary, since the collected result is discarded anyway. `forEach` would suffice.

Comment: your entire `.collect(Collectors.toList())` is useless, you already _have that_ as a `List`, from the very beginning, your entire `map` returns `item`. all you need to count whatever matches the predicate. streams are very much useless here.

Comment: As a side note, your example function has an n+1 problem in looking up the profiles (database lookup per employee). If possible/supported by your stack, you should get the profiles in one call by doing something like `List<UserProfile> users = userDao.findById(employeeProfileIds)`;

Comment: @AndyTurner at first, i didn't knew that we can call one method and return the item as per the conditon satisfied. i got the solution. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
Long count =Employees.stream()
                .filter((item) ->{
                    UserProfile user = userDao.findById(item.getUserProfileId());
                    return ("domainName").equals(user.getDomain()) && ("agencyCode").equals(user.getAgencyNumber());
                }).count();
```

Comment: i took others answers as suggestions and finally this worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
long count = getEmployeeList().stream()
                              .map(Employee::getUserProfileId)
                              .map(userDao::findById)
                              .filter(user -> "domainName".equals(user.getDomain())
                                      && "agencyCode".equals(user.getAgencyNumber()))
                              .count();
```

Comment: `.filter(user -> "domainName".equals(user.getDomain())).filter(user -> "agencyCode".equals(user.getAgencyNumber()))`

Answer (score 0):

If you still need the original objects you can create a map with a boolean key. Something like this:

```
List<Employee> Employees = getEmployeeList();
    Map<Boolean, List<Employee>> result = Employees.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(employee -> {
            var user = userDao.findById(item.getUserProfileId()));
            return ("domainName").equals(user.getDomain()) && ("agencyCode").equals(user.getAgencyNumber());
        }
        ));
```

Then you can call count on the list you want.

```
result.get(false).count();
```